# MapServer dumps error: msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Error (ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries)

Tags: postgis, mapserver

Using the following WFS: `http://dev-maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wosis_latest.map` on QGIS 2.18 and then opening the QGIS query builder on layer `ms:wosis_latest_profiles`, and running the following query:

`profile_id IN (69728,69916,69525,69903,69486,69607)`

We end up with the following error on MapServer's side :

`MapServer outputs a msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Error (ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries) error.`

From the logs we have a rather extensive SQL query: https://pastebin.com/cQDXM0Hp

Basically MapServer sends a query to postgis that contains:

```
((st_intersects(geom,ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((-184.2090000000000032 
-184.2090000000000032 -54.8890999999999991))')
```

And here is the problem, for the query to be successful we need for `ST_GeomFromText` to indicate the `SRID=4326`, otherwise we have the error  `Operation on mixed SRID geometries` and no reply from MapServer

The WFS service runs `mapserver7.6/gdal2.4/proj4` and `postgis ("POSTGIS="2.5.4" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3" PROJ="Rel. 7.0.1, May 1st, 2020" GDAL="GDAL 3.0.4)`

The mapfile has the  indication of layer projection and simple data connection:

```
 LAYER
        NAME "wosis_latest_profiles"
    PROJECTION
        'init=epsg:4326'
    TYPE POINT
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "...."
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
    DATA "geom from web_services.wosis_latest_profiles"
```

Is this a problem related to the PostGIS version / GDAL combinations, some miss configuration on MapServer, bug on QGIS? Any tips on how to debug it?

Comment: Try with `DATA "geom from web_services.wosis_latest_profiles using srid=4326"`

Comment: The suggestion  given by @user30184 is correct and solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved usng: `DATA "geom from web_services.wosis_latest_profiles using srid=4326"`